# Why this If conditions is always going to else?

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this conditions:

```
 if(!empty($numerofiles)) { // <-- WHEN THIS ARRAY IS EMPTY

                for ($i=0; $i < $numerofiles; $i++) {
                    $allowed =  array('doc','pdf','jpg','jpeg','xls','docx','xlsx');
                    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                     // BLA BLA BLA SOME CODE

                    if(in_array($ext,$allowed)) {

                        // BLA BLA SOME CODE

                    } else { // <-- ..IT SEND ME FOR THIS ELSE

                        $this->Comment->delete($this->Comment->id);
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Tipo de arquivo não permitido', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_fail'));
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));

                    }

                }
        }  else { // <-- BUT THIS SHOULD TO GO HERE

        }
    $this->Session->setFlash('Comentário adicionado com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
```

When in my first `if`, `$numerofiles` is empty, this is sending me for the `else` of the second `if`.
But, I want that if the `$numerofiles` is `empty` its jump and send for the end of the code.
What is wrong?

Comment: what do $ext and $allowed look like? $ext should be the value and $allowed should be the array, just making sure that's known

Comment: what does `empty($numerofiles)` returns? true or false ?

Comment: @prash $numerofiles is empty!!

Comment: so `(!empty($numerofiles)` evaluates to true and control goes inside teh if statement

Comment: @SS781 this if returns false

Comment: i think you dont need the not operator '`!`' . Do you understand?

Comment: if(!empty($numerofiles)) { // <-- When this is "NOT" empty...

Comment: you might wanna put the else before the last edning bracket }

Comment: @Medda86 It's the case. If this is "NOT" empty, the code runs. But is empty, is runnig that "else"

Comment: @prash I need `!`because I just want to run the `if`, if `$numerofiles` was not empty

Comment: You sure that's the one? maybe is the last rows that runs. put them before the last bracket

Comment: @Igor Martins: try to provide a reproducible piece of code. The self-contained one so that we could copy-paste it and see the behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: see my descriptive explanation below . see if it helps

Comment: Maybe need to use `if(count($numerofiles) > 0)` instead of `empty` because `empty` only evaluates to true if the array count = 0. What does `var_dump($numerofiles)` produce?

Comment: What you are saying if $numerofiles is empty its send you to inside `else` which is quite not possible. If by any chance your $numerofiles looks like as-
`$numerofiles=> array('file1', 'file2', '', null)` it will create a infinite loop of course cause you used '$i < $numerofiles' in 'for' loop. I would like to see your $numerofiles array. Could you please update your question?

Comment: @IgorMartins see edited answer. check if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

change `if(!empty($numerofiles))` to `if(empty($numerofiles))`

You are checking **if it is not empty**, whereas what you need to check is **if it is empty**

Also, You said `empty($numerofiles)`evaluate to false. This means it is not empty. Then again you put a not operator, so you negate it, now the meanining is 'if it is empty'

The empty() function is used to check whether a variable is empty or not.

```
Return value

FALSE if var_name has a non-empty and non-zero value.

Value Type : Boolean

List of empty things :

"0" (0 as a string)
0 (0 as an integer)
"" (an empty string)
NULL
FALSE
"" (an empty string)
array() (an empty array)
$var_name; (a variable declared but without a value in a class)
```

[Source](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/empty.php)

**Edit:**

looks like you still didn't came out of this issue.

lemme try again..

Step 1: `if(!empty($numerofiles))`  => `if(NOT (number of files is EMPTY))`

The key thing here is the `boolean` value of (number of files is EMPTY)

In your comment , You said `empty($numerofiles)`evaluate to false

So (number of files is EMPTY) is FALSE

Looking again on Step 1:

`if(NOT (FALSE))` => `if(TRUE)`

So your actual code, for this scenario, for the current input,
 while execution is if(TRUE)

Since it is `if(TRUE)`, the control goes inside. Agree?

Comment: No. I just want to run the `if` if the `$numerofiles` isnt empty. But when it is, this is runing the else inside

Comment: @Igor Martins: it's not possible.

Comment: @IgorMartins your question is poor, we cant even reproduce your issue, because your code is not really relevant

Comment: he is confusing. that's fine.. see you said "But when it is empty, this is runing the else inside". But you also said, `empty($numerofiles)` evaluate to false , meaning numberoffiles is not empty. So you think it is empty, but actually it is not empty. If it was empty, `empty($numerofiles)` MUST evaluate to true.

Comment: @Igor Martins: we won't debug it. Provide the small reproducible piece of it. http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: sorry for one post on empty. I thought, you have your own empty().

Comment: edited my code. When my array coming is empty, this is ruining the code anyway

Comment: `if (empty($arr)) {
  // it's empty
} else {
  // it's not empty  
}`  This is how it works. You are not showing us the heart of the issue. What is `$numerofiles`?

Comment: @Igor Martins: check http://www.sscce.org/ and provide the corresponding piece of code. Otherwise you'll waste time guessing

Comment: @zerkms Thanks a lot for that link, That was informative